# Using REST to retrieve lists

Tags: office-365, rest

I have entered the following into Firefox to retrieve my lists

[image]

and I get this back

[image]

I was expecting xml, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: For raw formatting, try e.g. Google Chrome.

Comment: You can also use IE. There you have maybe change the Feed Settings. http://spdoctor.net/Home/ErrorMessage/internet-explorer-cannot-display-this-feed

Comment: Please don't make changes to your question in a way that the original meaning is changed. Consider [asking a new question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), if you experience new/different problems, e.g. that you're having problems with a certain REST endpoint (instead of having problems with Firefox).

Comment: Sorry I have created another post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess Firefox treated the XML returned by the REST API like an atom feed.

[RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/restclient/) is a nice Firefox plugin you can use for interacting with SharePoint's REST API.